# Could someone read the megillah on Purim night over the telephone and be motzi someone in another time zone where it is already Purim morning?

Tags: halacha, purim

As stated in [THIS HEBREW ARTICLE](http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9C), (I'm sure there should be English language material on the subject too), There is a *machlokes* (disagreement) among the poskim whether one can do Mitzvos which require saying / hearing (kiddush, megillah, brachos, etc.) by listening to someone reciting/reading the appropriate material over the telephone.

According to the poskim who opine that one could be yotze the mitzvah through the telephone, could someone read the megillah on Purim night over the telephone and be motzi someone in another time zone where it is already Purim morning or vice versa?

If this is valid, would it work also for someone who is in another country who reads the megilla on the day of the fourteenth of Adar for someone who is in Yerushalayim for the night reading of the fifteenth of Adar, or vice versa?

Comment: Or vice versa, I suppose. I guess the underlying question is whether the underlying kavana has to include *which* reading, not just that they’re fulfilling Mikra Megillah.

Comment: @DonielF Yes, plus maybe the day reading works for the night person but not the night reading for the day person, because the day is the main reading, And maybe they both only work if they are the same chiyuv - 14th or 5th.

Comment: You might have luck finding discussion of a Ben Ir reading for a Ben Krakh on the 14th after Plag.

Comment: My understanding is that the "main" reading is during the day. This the "main" mitzvah. Perhaps, that factor plays into the mitvah obligations of the reader and the listener. Are the night and morning reading both considered "obligatory" mitzvoth and are they separate mitzvoth? Is one a mitzvah (the daytime) and the other "minhag"? Some of a few factors that we may need to consider, here.